# c# string split ignores empty values between delimiters

Tags: c#, string, debugging, split, outofrangeexception

Hey i already asked this but its not solved still, nothing worked , here my complete code:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace Insertss
{
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ReadWrite("projektangebote.txt", "inserts.txt");
    }

    static void ReadWrite(string readName, string writeName)
    {
        StreamReader streamReader;
        StreamWriter streamWriter;
        string str;
        List<string> values = new List<string>();
        streamReader = File.OpenText(readName);
        str = streamReader.ReadLine();
        streamWriter = new StreamWriter(writeName);

        while (str != null)                                         
        {
            values.Add(str);                                   
            str = streamReader.ReadLine();               
        }

        foreach (string a in values)
        {
            int temp = 1;
            String[] temparray = a.Split(';');
            streamWriter.WriteLine("Insert into table Firma values({0},'{1}','{2}')", temp, temparray[1], temparray[4]);
            temp++;
        }
        streamReader.Close();
    }
    }
}
```

Ok i insert:

PR_Arbeitstitel;PR_Bereich;PR_Firma_Name;PR_Firma_Organisation;PR_Massnahme;PR_Standort;PR_ProjektTeamDaten_ProjektOrt

Überarbeitung der SAV Seite;b.i.b.;;;;PB;

But and the 2nd row ( Überarbeitung der SAV Seite;b.i.b.;;;;PB; ) i get a IndexOutOfRangeException because:
[image: Debugged]

Anyone knows how i can solve this problem ?
Either insert just some char or a space ..

Comment: Your string is `JAVA-Apllication;b.i.b;Novabig....` so it has 3 entries see debuger

Comment: @DGibbs yes i asked it but nothing worked of it, i should have there posted my whole code i guess

Comment: @wudzik yes thats the problem if you read

Comment: @user3107760 he says that you are showing different string in debugger (which is obviously throws exception), not one you are mentioning in question

Comment: @user3107760 your string presented in debugger does not match string in question

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy not it ignores ;;  those where nothing is in there and i get IndexOutOfRangeException because ignoring ;;; those doesnt create my temparray[4]

Comment: Überarbeitung der SAV Seite;b.i.b.;;;;PB; <- this is not the row that throws the exception. Search for a row with Novabit Informationssysteme GmbH. It is always a good idea to check the array length before accessing an array created with split and dynamic input.

Comment: @wudzik youre right, my file has more than 570rows each of it projekt data, but somehow a few of them dont contain 7elements in this case only 3, i didnt know that , thx for all your help

Answer (score 1):

> JAVA-Apllication;b.i.b;Novabig....

This is string you are splitting -> see debugger variable `a`, also you can see that temparray contains parts of string I presented.

it is possible you are reading wrong file (check names and directories). You can check manually which lines are read in debugger and see if it matches expected value.

Split string is working here fine, for string `a` it should give array of 3, because string `a` has only two `;`'s

Comment: I want to split: Überarbeitung der SAV Seite;b.i.b.;;;;PB; i want it to return an array of 7 elements

Comment: @user3107760 it does not matter what you want to split. It matters only what you are actually splitting

Comment: @user3107760 as I suggested try to inspect which file you are opening and If file contains data you are expecting. Without content of that file I can not suggest any more. For now I see you are splitting wrong string

Comment: @wudzik oh now i see what you mean, my file looks like this : http://s7.directupload.net/images/131217/62lb4eer.png